# Django - Slugify string and use it only in url

Tags: django

I have `get_aboslute_url` function in my model in Django. Here is my code:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('detail', args=[self.author.full_name, self.title])
```

Here is my code for `detail` function:

```
def detail(request, author, title):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book,
                             author__full_name=author,
                             title=title)

    context = {'book': book}

    return render(request, 'booksreview/books_list.html', context)
```

And here is my problem. I want to use `author` and `title` as a slug in my url. So url should look like this `author-name/title-of-book`. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = ......
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
             self.slug = slugify(self.author__full_name + self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: You have to call the parent method too: `super(Subject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`. Also expand the method definition like this: `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't show how the url should look like. Check me edit.